# Polymer 1.0 Type Extension Select Element

Tags: polymer, native, element

My Polymer 1.0 Type Extension Select Element does not display correctly when I insert the below code into the Polymer Starter Kit. The element displays as a select arrow with no options.  I appreciate your help!

Contents of my-products.html (this file resides in the "my-products" folder in a similar way that my-list.html resides in the "my-list" folder):

```
<dom-module id="my-products">
    <template>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-products',
            extends: 'select'
        });
    </script>
    </dom-module>
```

Elements.html code:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-products/my-products.html">
```

Index.html code:

```
<select is="my-products"> </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the <select>  inside the template since the way you are using it already implies a wrapping <select>, overall yielding:

```
<select><select>(options)</select></select>
```

This works instead:

```
<dom-module id="my-products">
    <template>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-products',
            extends: 'select'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

If you want to have <select> in the template remove the "extends" property from your Polymer initialization object and just use <my-products></my-products> in index.html.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you, Igor!

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to accept correct answers.

Comment: Done and thanks for pointing that out.  I did not know about that process.